# Server Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am learning Next auth. I am getting this error when i load the website:

**Server Error
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.**

This is happening only when I added the auth logic in my navbar. Here's the code of Navbar component:

```
import { Dialog, Disclosure, Popover, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import {
  ArrowPathIcon,
  Bars3Icon,
  ChartPieIcon,
  CursorArrowRaysIcon,
  FingerPrintIcon,
  SquaresPlusIcon,
  XMarkIcon,
} from '@heroicons/react/24/outline'
import { ChevronDownIcon, PhoneIcon, PlayCircleIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid'
import Link from 'next/link'
import type {
  GetServerSidePropsContext,
  InferGetServerSidePropsType,
} from "next"
import { getProviders, signIn } from "next-auth/react"
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import options from '../../pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]';
const products = [
  { name: 'Analytics', description: 'Get a better understanding of your traffic', href: '#', icon: ChartPieIcon },
  { name: 'Engagement', description: 'Speak directly to your customers', href: '#', icon: CursorArrowRaysIcon },
  { name: 'Security', description: 'Your customers’ data will be safe and secure', href: '#', icon: FingerPrintIcon },
  { name: 'Integrations', description: 'Connect with third-party tools', href: '#', icon: SquaresPlusIcon },
  { name: 'Automations', description: 'Build strategic funnels that will convert', href: '#', icon: ArrowPathIcon },
]
const callsToAction = [
  { name: 'Watch demo', href: '#', icon: PlayCircleIcon },
  { name: 'Contact sales', href: '#', icon: PhoneIcon },
]

function classNames(...classes:String[]) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}

async function Navbar ({session}) {

  return (
    <header  style={{backgroundColor:"#f85606"}}>
      <nav className="mx-auto flex max-w-7xl items-center justify-between py-6" aria-label="Global">
        <div className="flex lg:flex mr-10">
          <a href="#" className="-m-1.5 p-1.5">
            <span className="sr-only">Your Company</span>
            <img className="h-10 w-auto" src="https://icms-image.slatic.net/images/ims-web/e650d6ca-1841-4646-b0e9-4ddbf2beb731.png" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
       
        <Popover.Group className="hidden lg:flex">
          <Popover className="relative">
            <Popover.Button className="flex pt-2 items-center text-md font-semibold leading-6 text-white">
              Product
              <ChevronDownIcon className="h-5 w-5 flex-none text-white" aria-hidden="true" />
            </Popover.Button>

            <Transition
              as={Fragment}
              enter="transition ease-out duration-200"
              enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-1"
              enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0"
              leave="transition ease-in duration-150"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0"
              leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-1"
            >
              <Popover.Panel className="absolute -left-8 top-full z-10 mt-3 w-screen max-w-md overflow-hidden rounded-3xl bg-white shadow-lg ring-1 ring-gray-900/5">
                <div className="p-4">
                  {products.map((item) => (
                    <div
                      key={item.name}
                      className="group relative flex items-center gap-x-6 rounded-lg p-4 text-sm leading-6 hover:bg-gray-50"
                    >
                      <div className="flex h-11 w-11 flex-none items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-gray-50 group-hover:bg-white">
                        <item.icon className="h-6 w-6 text-gray-600 group-hover:text-indigo-600" aria-hidden="true" />
                      </div>
                      <div className="flex-auto">
                        <a href={item.href} className="block font-semibold text-gray-900">
                          {item.name}
                          <span className="absolute inset-0" />
                        </a>
                        <p className="mt-1 text-gray-600">{item.description}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
                <div className="grid grid-cols-2 divide-x divide-gray-900/5 bg-gray-50">
                  {callsToAction.map((item) => (
                    <a
                      key={item.name}
                      href={item.href}
                      className="flex items-center justify-center gap-x-2.5 p-3 text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-100"
                    >
                      <item.icon className="h-5 w-5 flex-none text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" />
                      {item.name}
                    </a>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </Popover.Panel>
            </Transition>
          </Popover>

          <div style={{width:"40rem"}} className="flex rounded-md shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-inset focus-within:ring-indigo-600">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="username"
                    id="username"
                    autoComplete="username"
                    className="block w-full flex-1 rounded-l-md border border-0 bg-white py-1.5 pl-1 text-white-900 placeholder:text-white-400 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                    placeholder="janesmith"
                  />
                  <span className="flex select-none rounded-r-md bg-white items-center pl-3 text-orange-900 sm:text-sm">workcation.com/</span>
                </div>
        </Popover.Group>
        <div className="hidden lg:flex lg:flex-1 lg:justify-end">
         
          <Link href="/User" className="text-sm mx-2 font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">
            User Home 
          </Link>
          <Link href="/" className="text-sm mx-2 font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">
            App Home 
          </Link>
          <Link href="/User/Cart" className="text-sm mx-2 font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">
            User Cart
          </Link>
          <Link href="/admin" className="text-sm mx-2 font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">
            Admin
          </Link>
          {/* {session ? <Link href="/api/auth/signout?callback=/">Logout</Link>: 
          <Link href="/api/auth/signin">Login</Link>
          } */}
        </div>
      </nav>
      
    </header>
  )
}
export default Navbar;

export async function getServerSideProps(context: GetServerSidePropsContext) {
  const session = await getServerSession(context.req, context.res, options)
 console.log(session)
  // If the user is already logged in, redirect.
  // Note: Make sure not to redirect to the same page
  // To avoid an infinite loop!
  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false,
      },
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {
      session,
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `Navbar` is returning a promise instead of a JSX Element. When you declare your function as `async`, it will always return a `Promise`. To fix this, you simply need to remove `async` in your function declaration, i.e.,

```
function Navbar({ session }) {
  // your function body
}
```

Tip: Since you are using Typescript, if you are using VSCode, you can always hover over your function name to see what Typescript infers your function signature as.

[image: Hover over function declaration in VSCode]